# compare two float list strings in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, automation, floating-point

```
a=['0.0','123.34'] #list
b=['0.0','123.34']

def isclose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0):
    return abs(a-b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)

isclose(a,b)
```

Error:

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
> ```

I tried to compare the two float lists in python but got the error. if matched otherwise show unmatched. Can anyone help me and provide me with an alternative way to do it.

Comment: why do you use strings in your lists and not floats?

Comment: You have lists of strings - not floats. The method wants a number, not strings. Also:  There is (for floats) a build-in for what you want to do .... [https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose)

Comment: Can you explain what the result of `['0.0','123.34'] - ['0.0','123.34']` is?
`

Comment: @PatrickArtner.. I need match the both lists and process the further the coding basis on match result.

Comment: Convert the lists to numpy float arrays first.

Comment: Is the **[numpy]`** tag supposed to mean something?  You don't have `numpy` arrays, or use `numpy` functions.  The task will be easy if the lists are actually numpy float arrays.

Answer (score 2):

There is no numpy in your code.

You have lists of strings - not floats. The method you use operates on numbers, not strings.

There is (for floats) an existing method to compare floats: [math.isclose](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose)

If you want to compare lists you need to iterate the list. If you want to check floats, you need to convert to float before checking:

```
# use what already exists
from math import isclose

a = ['0.0','123.34','42'] 
b = ['0.0','123.34','3.141']

r = []

# same length lists, use zip to iterate pairwise, use enumerate for index
for idx, (aa, bb) in enumerate(zip(a,b)):
    # convert to floats
    aaa = float(aa)
    bbb = float(bb)

    # append if not close
    if not isclose(aaa,bbb):
        r.append((idx, (aaa,bbb)))

# print results
for w in r:
    print("On index {0} we have {1} != {2}".format(w[0],*w[1]), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
On index 2 we have 42.0 != 3.141
```

Comment: ..can we store in a list ..("On index {0} we have {1} != {2}".format(w[0],*w[1]), sep="\n")..if yes please tell me the code

Comment: @vipin It seems to me you are out of the water regarding your skill level with python and what you want to do. Take tutorials? There IS a list with the results - it is `r` in this code - `r` contains tuples of the INDEX and a tuple of the values at that index int the lists IF they are not close .... If you want the text stored, then don't print it but put it into a list. Coding is not asking others to provide code for you - that is (bad) management (if you can't understand the solution you get provided with). coding is puzzling stuff out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the '-' operator with lists. The code `abs(a-b)` is first trying to do `a-b` which it cannot do as `a` and `b` are lists.

You can write a function to subtract each index in list `b` from each corresponding index in list `a` and place the result of each computation in a new list with the same index.

Alternatively use numpy's `numpy.subtract()` method to carry out this computation.

Furtheremore, `abs()` cannot be used on a list object, you can write your own code that iterates over each element in a list and calculates the absolute value of each element or use numpy's `numpy.absolute()`.

Comment: can you please the sample code as well.

Comment: To build on @Patrick Anter's suggestion. You can use a library's method to achieve this.
If you take `numpy.isclose()`, you are able to provide it two lists of floats, and in return get whether each of the values in the lists were close.

*Example:*
`numpy,isclose([float(i) for i in a], [float(i) for i in b])` produces the output `[ True  True False]`

Answer (score 0):

With python you can't substract list object from each other. Moreover, you can't substract str object from each other.

You can do it with oneline :

```
a=['0.0','123.34'] #list
b=['0.0','123.34']

def isclose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0):

    return all([True if abs(float(i)-float(j)) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(float(i)), abs(float(j))), abs_tol) else False for i,j in zip(a,b) ])


isclose(a,b)
```

return True if both elements of lists are close

Greetings

Comment: I tried to execute above but got this error..TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'list'

Comment: Sorry i corrected the error, now it works well